# Spark SQL -Problems with saving DataFrame to database through JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sybase

I have a `test` table registered from `DataFrame`using `registerTempTable`.

And I query the `test`table:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select no,vipgroupname,sum(name) as count from test group by no,vipgroupname limit 5")
```

Below is the result:

```
df.show()
+---+---------------+----------------------------+
|no |   vipgroupname|                count       |
+---+---------------+----------------------------+
| 1 |       testa   |                         636|
| 2 |       testb   |                         28 |
| 3 |       testc   |                         21 |
| 4 |       testd   |                         142|
| 5 |       teste   |                         79 |
+---+---------------+----------------------------+
```

Try to save it as table `test`to external database (`Sybase` in this case)

```
    properties = {
        "user": "test",
        "password": "Test123!"
    }
    url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:9.16.18.30:5566?ServiceName=test"
    df.write.mode('overwrite').jdbc(url=url, table="test",properties=properties

)
```

This action was all right and the data was all saved to `Sybase` in table `test`.
But when I executed this again to verify the overwrite behavior.

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').jdbc(url=url, table="test",properties=properties)
```

All I got was the exception:

```
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o547.jdbc.
     java.sql.SQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -110: Item 'test' already exists
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(SybConnection.java:2780)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.handleSQLE(SybStatement.java:2665)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:295)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:272)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.updateLoop(SybStatement.java:2515)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeUpdate(SybStatement.java:2499)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SybPreparedStatement.java:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:370)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor95.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I thought mode `overwrite` will delete current table and create new table. But this exception seems not the case.
And the exception came with mode `append` too.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook(installed by `Anaconda 5.3.1` ) to run above code and Spark version is `1.5.1`.

Am I using something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Since spark 1.4 , the behavior of  write mode in  DataFrameWriter didn't change. I am not sure about sysbase but if you point to spark the guess would be the default savemode is hitting ?  which is 'ErrorIfExists' to throw an error message if a table with the same name already exists. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@mode(saveMode:org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[T]   i see save "mode" syntax out there as ...df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc() , something differs with yours?

Comment: @Karthick Thanks for reply. Yes it seems the default mode "ErrorifExists" always hits.Sorry to mention I'm using Pyspark here and get reference from  https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframewrite#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter. I tried `df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)` and got  `NameError: name 'SaveMode' is not defined`. Maybe this is not available for pyspark 1.5.1.